# How to write a vertically centered dot between brackets with less space?

Tags: spacing, brackets

I want to write a dot between brackets, but I want it to be:

1. Vertically centered, like using `$(\cdot)$`
2. With the same space between the dot and the brackets as if I wrote `$(.)$`

That is, I want something like this (`$(\cdot)$`):

[image]

But with less space between the brackets and the dot, an spacing similar to the following:

[image]

However, I also want the dot to be vertically centered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I get the same spacing with `$(\cdot)$` as with `$(.)$`. I don't know why yours is wider. Do you use some special package that may change the spacing?

Comment: In addition to what Pieter said the dot sits far too high in your first image, so whatever is happening is due to code you are withholding.

Comment: I found out that the problem was that I included the package `lmodern`. Once the package was removed, the problem was solved.